# Hide "More Options" menu on Docusign envelope view rest API v2

Tags: php, docusignapi

Using Docusign rest api v2, is it possible to turn off the "More Options" dropdown (pictured)?

Specifically I'd like to remove the "Finish Later" and "Decline to Sign" options.

I'm using PHP POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes, and then POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient

Thanks!

[image: More options menu]

Answer (score 0):

Nope, sorry, this is not something that DocuSign support at this point.

Comment: Lol yeah more than a year later I kinda guessed that Inbar  Any plans to add this? It would be a nice feature for those of us who just want to use docusign for embedded signing.

Comment: I'm not sure, you could email feedback@docusign.com to provide feedback. If you explain why you need it and what are the various scenarios that this is relevant for - you may have more chance of the product team considering it.